# Unhandled exception linking to DLL

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, console-application, ace

I have a problem when I link to a DLL I created. The exception thrown is `Unhandled exception at 0x000007FA17461069 (ntdll.dll)`. The strange thing is that this only happens if I link the DLL in a win32 application but NOT in a win32 Console application. The problem seems to be something that deals with thread creation.

The call stack is as follows:

```
msvcr110d.dll!_callthreadstartex() Line 354            C
msvcr110d.dll!_threadstartex(void * ptd) Line 337      C
```

The DLL contains implementations for the ACE proactor framework, using the operating systems I/O completion ports. It runs fine in a console application, but not in a win32 windowed application.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: as requested by comments below:

The line of code that throws the exception is `ACE_Service_Config::open(GetCommandLineA());`

I use the ACE Configuration framework to so I load my DLL dynamically with a svc.conf file. This is the only line of code that needs to be written to the `main` function of the console program.

I tried writing this line after the WM_CREATE message is caught. It crashes.

Comment: What happens if you run it in release mode instead of debug?

Comment: Find out where the exception is thrown. Make sure you are using the DLL and EXE linked against the same DLLs, not e.g. one using the debug variant but not the other. Check the log to find out which DLL exactly is loaded. Find out where the exact differences between the working and non-working versions are. Find the code that throws the exception. Distill a minimal example and post that here.

Comment: @ Arun: mmm... haven't tried that yet. I will try it. However, as running it in release mode I will have to rebuild all of my libraries which will take some time. Is there any difference between release and debug mode?

Comment: @ doomster: All libraries are built in debug mode with platform x64

Comment: When you say 'linking to the DLL', do you mean that the crash happens without you calling/running any code from the DLL?

Comment: No. I've ran the init function I wrote in the DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a console application ACE will redefine main to make sure it gets correctly initialized. When making a win32 windows application this trick doesn't work. You have to call ACE::init() and ACE::fini() yourself, see ACE_wrappers/tests/ACE_Init_Test.cpp for an example how you can do this.

Comment: Did the trick. Thanks a lot. By the way, I have another ACE question, you seem very experienced with ACE so I'm wondering if you could help me out with that also.

Comment: The link to the question is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705227/unhandled-exception-when-using-ace-service-config. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just added a comment there, the ACE mailing lists are really a better place to ask.